# How to generate meshes from pre made modules

Tags: mesh

There are different options for individual parts of the mesh (modules). How can Blender quickly generate mesh made up of random combination of these modules?
For example, there are different options for the first, second floor and roof of the house. How can I quickly generate a street of random houses?

[image]

Comment: I suppose Animation Nodes add-on will be a good place to start